# amazon connect and amazon lex work in Saudi Arabia region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, ivr, amazon-connect

We are building IVR based application where user can talk to voice bot to get his query resolved. as our Team decided to go with amazon connect and amazon lex to build this application.

But our client is from saudi arabia region and we are not sure that does it work In there region.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below the list of region Lex is available,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_Reference.html

and list of region-specific services - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/

Still, you can connect to API of the available region and can pass date of the time zone you want to use.

To set the time zone used to resolve dates so that it is relative to the user's time zone, use the x-amz-lex:time-zone request attribute. If you do not specify a time zone in the x-amz-lex:time-zone attribute, the default is America/New York.

Comment: so if i change time zone it will work in saudi arabia ?

Comment: It should. Please find one the answer I have given for relatively same issue and he was trying it from Australia - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47058489/7666972

Comment: thanx what about amazon connect is it possible to use in saudi arabia?

Comment: Hmm not very sure about Amazon connect. It would good if you raise it as a separate question so that if anybody knows will answer it. Also, it would be worth if you check with the guy who implemented in Australia. I am sure he can share you more input :)